# Wiring 220 to AC/DC transformer help?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, ac

On this AC/DC power module the terminals are labeled N and L, can I wire 220 line to line both to N and L? See link to part

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/RAC10-K_277-1661832.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says it can handle 305VAC so putting in 220-240VAC will be fine.

**If you are in the US:** with 220VAC there is no neutral wire,
so L1 and L2 are what you will wire to that module.  It doesn't matter which one goes to which.

If you are somewhere else that uses 220VAC as their standard household voltage like most of Europe, then you will have a line wire (brown) and neutral wire(blue) to connect accordingly.

Comment: That depends on where you live. In ~60 % of the world, 220VAC would mean neutral to phase, i.e. neural wire.

Comment: @winny True, updated to cover that.